# Downloading MODIS products with R package rts

Tags: r, modis

I'm having trouble batch downloading MODIS products with the rts package in R.
I'm using the code below to download the MODIS products:

```
library(rts)
library(raster)
library(RCurl)

bands = "0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"

ModisDownload(x='MOD11A2',h=c(24,25),v=c(5,6),version='006',dates=c('2011.01.01','2011.03.31'),mosaic=F,bands_subset = bands, proj=F)
```

When I run the code, I get this error message:

```
Error in .._MD_curlHandle <<- RCurl::getCurlHandle() : cannot change value of locked binding for '.._MD_curlHandle'
```

I'm not sure what this error message means.

Comment: What version of R and rts?

Comment: I'm using RStudio 3.4.2 and rts 1.0 -38.

Comment: I can't run this as is because it needs a user/pass, but reading the docs seems to say the "bands" should be space-separated instead of comma-separated. Might not make any difference...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the latest version of the rts package that is currently on GitHub. This is fixed there. Following is the way to install it:

devtools::install_github('babaknaimi/rts')